# String Array on JTextArea output should be in Tabular form

Tags: java, arrays, string, jtextarea

I need help 
I tried this program for making report with simple print on JTextArea 
input is in simple String Array so i have to just print it or display it as in tabular form 
It looks something like this:

```
-----------------------------
|col1|col2|this is some     |
|    |    |very long        |
|    |    |Text Here!       |
-----------------------------
```

thanks in advance .

```
package reportlast;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import static reportlast.Padding.padLeft;

    public class ReportLast extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
        String[] colName = new String[]           {"Date","Account.No","Description","Deposit","Withdraw"};

        String A[][] = {{"13/12/2013", "101", "AlphaSoftInfotekNashik", "3000", "0"},
                   {"15/12/2013", "103", "Bank Ladger 2 xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "5000", "0"}};
        String[][] B = new String[3][5];

        Container c;
         JTextArea outputArea;
        //JScrollPane js1;    
        JButton b;

        public void init() {    
        c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());    
        outputArea = new JTextArea(20, 80);
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED);
        outputArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border,
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
        c.add(outputArea);
        //js1=new JScrollPane(outputArea);
       // add(js1);
        b = new JButton("Show Report");
        b.addActionListener(this);
        c.add(b);

       }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        outputArea.setEditable(false);
        outputArea.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.PLAIN,14));
        outputArea.setText(" ");
        outputArea.append("ALPHASOFT -- BANK LADGER , REPORTS.\n\n");
        outputArea.append("Sr.No");
        for(int j=0;j<colName.length;j++)
        {
            outputArea.append("\t"+colName[j]);                
        }          
        outputArea.append("\n");    
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            //someLine = String.format(format);
            for (int j = 0; j < A[i].length; j++) {
                B[i][j] = A[i][j];    
                while (B[i][j] != null) {
                    A[i][j] = B[i][j];
                    B[i][j] = null;    
                    if (A[i][j].length() > 20){
                        int split = 20;
                        for (int n = 20; n > 0; n--) {
                            String bc = A[i][j].substring(n, n + 1);
                            char result = A[i][j].charAt(n);    
                            if (result != ' ') {

                            } else {
                                split = n + 1;    
                                break;
                            }    
                        }
                            String s =String.valueOf(A[i][j].substring(0, split));
                            if(s!=null)
                            {                                    
                                outputArea.append(s);                                
                            }
                        //outputArea.append(s);    
                        B[i][j] = A[i][j].substring(split, A[i][j].length());    
                    } else {
                        // outputArea.append(j + 1);
                        outputArea.append(String.valueOf("\t"+A[i][j]));    
                    }
                }    
            }
        }          
    }    
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: i tried this above code my self but its not look in Table format so plz do something for me actually my boss completely suck me on this work he told me dont use JTable and even \r\n \t !

Answer (score 1):

I put another `outputArea.append("\n");` at the very end of the outer `for` loop and it seems to work. You just need to fix the format spacing of the data

**Edit:** Try this out. Just play around with the `format` variable

```
protected final String format = "%-20s%-20s%-45s%-20s%-20s\n";

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    outputArea.setEditable(false);
    outputArea.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    outputArea.setText(" ");
    outputArea.append("ALPHASOFT -- BANK LADGER , REPORTS.\n\n");
    outputArea.append("Sr.No");
    outputArea.append("\n");

    String date;
    String account;
    String desc;
    String depos;
    String withd;

    date = colName[0];
    account = colName[1];
    desc = colName[2];
    depos = colName[3];
    withd = colName[4];

    outputArea.append(String.format(format, date, account, desc, depos, withd));


    for (String[] A1 : A) {
        date = A1[0];
        account = A1[1];
        desc = A1[2];
        depos = A1[3];
        withd = A1[4];
        outputArea.append(String.format(format, date, account, desc, depos, withd));
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for help, but it just work for header of table structure i need help about display rowXcolumn in above mentioned program so plz help me to solve this issue.@peeskillet